# PHP Replace and edit array elements from keywords

Tags: php, arrays, replace, nested

I have the following input:

```
$input = [
    0 => '$id000001',
    1 => '$id000002',
    2 => '$id000003',
    3 => 'Alexandre'
];

$keywords = [
    '$id000001' => 'function_name($+2)',
    '$id000002' => '$user',
    '$id000003' => '$-1 = $+1'
];
```

I would like to implement a function that will replace `$input` elements with `$keywords` elements, with the following output:

```
[
    0 => 'function_name($+2)',
    1 => '$user',
    2 => '$-1 = $+1',
    3 => 'Alexandre'
];
```

Here is the point, my function have to replace all `$(+|-)[0-9]+` elements (like `$+2`, `$-1`, ...) with `$input` element value (after it has been replaced) and then **remove them**. The number is the row offset index :

- `$-1 = $+1` will be replaced with `$user = 'Alexandre'`
- `function_name($+2)` will be replaced with `$-1 = $+1` (wich is `$user = 'Alexandre'`)

So, the final output will be:

```
[
    0 => function_name($user = 'Alexandre')
]
```

Comment: Use [`array_map()`](http://fr2.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-map.php), and `$keywords[$input[$key]]` if `$input[$key]` exists.

Comment: Yes, already tried that. But i would like to remove array rows that has been replaced by `$(+|-)[0-9]+`. I have a replacement order to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after trying to fix infinite recurtions, i found this :

```
function translate($input, array $keywords, $index = 0, $next = true)
{
    if ((is_array($input) === true) &&
        (array_key_exists($index, $input) === true))
    {
        $input[$index] = translate($input[$index], $keywords);

        if (is_array($input[$index]) === true)
            $input = translate($input, $keywords, $index + 1);
        else
        {
            preg_match_all('/\$((?:\+|\-)[0-9]+)/i', $input[$index], $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

            foreach ($matches as $match)
            {
                $element = 'false';
                $offset = ($index + intval($match[1]));
                $input = translate($input, $keywords, $offset, false);

                if (array_key_exists($offset, $input) === true)
                {
                    $element = $input[$offset];

                    unset($input[$offset]);
                }

                $input[$index] = str_replace($match[0], $element, $input[$index]);
            }

            if (empty($matches) === false)
                $index--;

            if ($next === true)
                $input = translate(array_values($input), $keywords, $index + 1);
        }
    }
    else if (is_array($input) === false)
        $input = str_replace(array_keys($keywords), $keywords, $input);

    return $input;
}
```

Maybe, someone could find some optimizations.